# Using pushViewController: animated:

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, push

I'm trying to use the pushViewController: animated: with a UIViewController. I have it housed in a UINavigationController with initWithRoot and it still doesn't work.

Here is my code? Am I doing something wrong?

```
CloudappSettingsViewController *cloud = [[CloudappSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cloud];
        [self pushViewController:nav animated:YES];
        [cloud release];
```

It always crashes when it gets up to the `[self pushViewController:nav animated:YES];`

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is "self" a UINavigationController?

It seems you are trying to push the navigation controller, but that is backwards. You should present the navigation controller and push additional views to it.

So the UIView you are in should already be in the nav controller then you would push cloud into that.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in your app delegate, just add the UINavigationController as a subview to your app's window. If you want to present the UINavigationController as a modal view controller then do this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

Comment: It's not in my AppDelegate. Its in my ViewController. I'm looking to achieve that push and pop animation for the settings. I have an idea on getting it working. Let me give that a shot now.   **Edit** setting the SettingsViewController as a UINavigationController didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

It will crash definitely because you set the nib to nil.

```
CloudappSettingsViewController *cloud = [[CloudappSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NibName goes here" bundle:nil];
```

Create a nib and assign it to your view controller.

Comment: I did try that earlier this morning. Is it even possible to use the pushViewController and popViewController on a UIViewController?

Comment: Yes it is definitely possible. In their view controller you can always go like this and do push and pop: [self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES]; or do the similar thing for popping. I just noticed in your code that you are calling just the SELF for pushing which i guess it'll cause the crash.